# How to define access control properly on n-level child object in Loopback?

Tags: acl, loopbackjs

I'm scratching my head for a while about the best way to define ACL on my models.
I've a model tree like this:
`Project -> Issue -> Objective -> Action -> Planning`
Each project is managed by few users (some have read-only access, others have full access). If user is not related to the project, he can't access it. Each child knows only its parent (parentId).

**How can I check that user X can access Planning Y?**

I've tested nested models and it works fine but only on the first level (`Project -> Issue`). I already tried a role-resolver where I pass through all parent models to Project but it's ugly and must be done for each model.
One told me to add projectId property on all children but it's clearly not clean.

Thank you very much for your help,
Thierry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest way is definitely to define a `belongsTo` `Project` relation for each sub-object (Issue, Objective, Action, Planning).

This way you can leverage the entire access control system from loopback and use dynamic roles.

You could also implement role resolving without it, but like you said, it has to be repeated for each model, and ultimately it is just writing more code and doing more queries for doing the exact same thing than the relation.